# Send alert email if CPU usage is continuously higher than a certain amount

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron

In a Linux / Unix server when the CPU usage go above a threshold value it need to send out a email alert. Propose a way to do it through cron tab and shell scripting.

Comment: why won't you do it through cron tab and shell scripting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done through following shell script and a frequent cron job.

cpu_monitor.sh

```
CPU=$(sar 1 5 | grep "Average" | sed 's/^.* //')

if [ $CPU -lt 20 ]
then
   cat mail_content.html | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
else
   echo "Normal"
fi
```

mail_content.html

```
From: donotreply@sample.com
To: info@sample.com
Subject: Subject of the mail
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<h1>CPU usage increased heigh</h1>
```

Here the script will take the CPU ideal percentage for each 1 seconds. And 5 samples will be taken. Then average of that ideal percentage will be passed to variable `CPU`. When the ideal goes below the 20% mail will be send out.

We can setup the cron with 5 minute duration.

```
*/5 * * * * cd /full/path/to/script/; ./cpu_monitor.sh;
```

Comment: Note that the `echo "Normal"` would send me an email each time CRON runs... because CRON sends me all output which are expected to be errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `uptime` command that displays (at the end) the average cpu usage for the last 15 minutes. This should be a reasonable time range in order to avoid short spikes in CPU usage. The `uptime` command shows the number of processes in a runnable state. If they are less than the CPU cores, the machine is not CPU bound, while if they are more than the CPU cores, the machines will start suffering. Let's say we agree that having the number of processes more than 2 times the number of cores is the level we want to be alerted.

```
# get the number of CPU cores using /proc/cpuinfo
#
ncpu=$(egrep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo)

#
# get the last number (only integer part) of uptime output
#
load=$(LC_ALL=C uptime  | sed -e 's/.*average: .* \([0-9]*\)\.[0-9][0-9]$/\1/')

#
# divide the $load number by the $ncpu and check if greather than alert level
#
if [ $(($load/$ncpu)) -gt 2 ]
then
   # send an e-mail to alerts@domain.tld.
   echo -e  "\nCPU usage is greather than twice the number of CPU cores for more than 15 minutes.\n" \
   | fold -s -w75 | mailx -s "CPU alert for $(hostname)" alerts@domain.tld
fi
```

It may be run from crontab adding this text as `/etc/cron.d/simplecpucheck`:

```
MAILTO=alerts@domain.tld
10,40 * * * * root /path/name/of/shell-script
```

Please note that I prefer to send e-mail from the shell script instead of crontab daemon since I may use a subject line more informative. I still leave the email address in crontab file in order to receive any other error (mainly syntax errors in my script and commands not found).

Comment: Your script is obviously not work. Find out why.

Comment: @Andrew, I did a test before posting this answer, and the script worked, at least on a Linux Debian machine. If anything is not working, please tell me what it is, so that I can correct this solution. Thank you.

Comment: no you did not test this script. Maybe you test another script, but not this one. Where does '$cpu' come from?

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, I just fixed the error you spotted.